# Adding a UIImage from a UIGraphics Context to a Tweet

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

I have a game that I've been working on for iOS.  We let our users tweet the results of their games and I thought it'd be fun to add a badge or something to the tweet to show details.

I create an image using UIKit.  Then, I attach that image in iOS 6.0 with `-[SLComposeViewController addImage:]` or in iOS 5.* with `[TWTweetComposeViewController addImage:]` but neither of them will attach an the image.

If I use Facebook or Weibo, the image attaches fine.  With Twitter, no luck at all.

Has anybody had any luck attaching an image to a tweet?

Comment: Does [TWTweetComposeViewController addImage:] return BOOL of YES or NO?

Comment: YES for Facebook and Weibo and NO for Twitter on iOS 6 and iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're receiving NO for the return value of `TWTweetComposeViewController`, the documentation says: YES if successful. NO if image does not fit in the currently available character space or the view was presented to the user.

Comment: Yeah.  I tried it with one of my icons which was 48px by 48px.  I was hoping the documentation would provide more information about why an image would be invalid, but I can't.  Do you have a recommendation to avoid exceeding my available character space?

Comment: It could be a bug with the character counting in the SDK. See https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5024

Comment: I see what you're saying . . . it doesn't matter what size the picture is . . . it can't create a link to it if the tweet is already too long.  I'm testing now.

Comment: FML.  I never tried to shorten the text.  Thanks for reading the documentation for me. :)